# Using UPDATE statement with a SELECT statement converting hexadecimal to text

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called Script_Data that has three columns - ScriptID (primary), RowOrder and ScriptData. each row value for ScripData is hexadecimal. For me to make sense of it, I convert it to text. I `CAST()` the ScriptData column into `VarChar` datatype using the following query

```
SELECT ScriptID, RowOrder, CAST(CAST(ScriptData AS varbinary(MAX)) AS varchar(MAX)) AS Converted_SD 
FROM Script_Data
```

Is it possible to UPDATE values in the ScriptData column when converted? I know that I would typically do something like this if not for converting:

```
UPDATE Script_Data
SET ScriptData='Sales'
WHERE ScriptData='Marketing';
```

Is it even possible to do something like this when I have it converted from hex to text? I've tried so many different queries, most of which include subqueries, but all failed.

Converting it changes this

```
| ScriptID | RowOrder | ScriptData |
------------------------------------
| 5008     | 1        | 0x435669787|
```

to this (I'm over simplifying the results)

```
| ScriptID | RowOrder | ScriptData |
------------------------------------
| 5008     | 1        | Sales      |
```

EDIT:
My best attempt seems to have been this query

```
UPDATE Script_Data
SET ScriptData='Engineering'
(SELECT ScriptID, RowOrder, CONVERT(varchar(max), ScriptData)
FROM Script_Data
WHERE ScriptData = 'Accounting')
```

But SQL is telling me that Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. I've tried to use CONVERT in creative ways to satisfy the error, but have not been successful. The ScriptData column is varbinary datatype with -1 length.

Comment: You can use `cast` in the `where` clause of the `update` statement as well.

Comment: @DaleK, SQL at least waited until I ran the query to yell at me rather than spit out syntax errors

`UPDATE Script_Data
SET ScriptData='Engineering'
(SELECT ScriptID, RowOrder, CONVERT(varchar(max), ScriptData) AS Converted_SD
FROM Script_Data
WHERE ScriptData = 'Accounting')`

SQL keeps telling me that I cannot convert varchar to varbinary and to use the CONVERT function instead, but that's what I'm using above. That's why I was wondering if CAST would work.

Comment: @DaleK - Post has been edited

Comment: Do you have a separate, *new* `VARCHAR(MAX)` column to receive the conversion?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to `cast` the new value to `varbinary` as part of the update.

```
UPDATE Script_Data SET
  ScriptData = CAST('Engineering' AS VARBINARY(MAX))
WHERE CAST(ScriptData AS VARCHAR(MAX)) = 'Accounting'
```

I won't ask why you are storing strings as `varbinary` because I'm sure you realise life would be much easier if you just stored it as a `varchar`.

Here is the test script I used:

```
declare @ScriptData table (ScriptData varbinary(max));

insert into @ScriptData (ScriptData)
values (0x435669787), (convert(varbinary(max),'Sales'));

select *, convert(varchar(max),ScriptData,3), CAST(ScriptData AS varchar(MAX)) from @ScriptData;

update @ScriptData set
  ScriptData = CAST('Marketing' AS VARBINARY(MAX))
where CAST(ScriptData AS varchar(MAX)) = 'Sales';

select *, convert(varchar(max),ScriptData,3), CAST(ScriptData AS varchar(MAX)) from @ScriptData;
```

Comment: Strange, it keeps telling me 0 rows affected. I checked the data and the old values are still there. I think this is a good starting point for me to play with though.

Comment: @aquamelli I've added the test script I used, which works. It might be that your data doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

For your `SELECT` query, the analogous `UPDATE` is to place conversion in the `SET` command assigning value to a new or different column, not the same column.

`UPDATE` is not a DDL  (data definition language) but a DML (data manipulation language) command. Hence, it only adjusts data but does not change a columns' defined data type. Consider an `ALTER` command to create a new `VARCHAR(MAX)` column then run `UPDATE` to assign value:

```
ALTER TABLE Converted_SD ADD ScriptData_Text VARCHAR(MAX);

UPDATE Converted_SD  
SET ScriptData_Text = CAST(CAST(ScriptData AS varbinary(MAX)) AS varchar(MAX));
```

Also, since `ALTER` is a DDL command, use it very sparingly and never in application code or stored procedure since it can adjust table schema and column definitions.